# Can't click anything, despite switching frames, on frame popup on Indeed when using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

## I'm trying to submit an application on indeed using Selenium WebDriver.

I've entered jobType, and jobLocation, pressed search, opened up first result, and in new tab, switched focus, and pressed apply. Now, a pop up appears changing the previously 1 iframe on page to 2. I switch to second iframe and then try to send keys to input text field of "name" yet no input field exists

```
        driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");       
        WebElement what = driver.findElement(By.id("text-input-what"));

        what.sendKeys("Java Programmer");
        WebElement where = driver.findElement(By.id("text-input-where"));

        Thread.sleep(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            where.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        }
        where.sendKeys("Toronto, ON");
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='icl-Button icl-Button--primary icl-Button--md icl-WhatWhere-button']"));

        submit.click();

        WebElement thirdElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[9]"));      

        thirdElement.click();

        System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));  
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement apply = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='icl-Button icl-Button--branded icl-Button--md']//div[@class='jobsearch-IndeedApplyButton-contentWrapper'][contains(text(),'Apply Now')]"));
        System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size());
        apply.click();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();


        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
//      Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size());

        WebElement inputName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-applicant.name']"));
        inputName.sendKeys("Adam Smith");
```

[html code on ref page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d49mD.jpg)
.
[Target indeed Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNeyh.jpg)

### The expected results are that i can input text to text field, and the actual is that it gives error message:

- **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: *no such element:* Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='input-applicant.name']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)**

Comment: You need to use "implicitlyWait" or "FluentWait" cause you need to give enough time to load all elements. you could also follow https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html, https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

Comment: I tried this. It did not work. If you look at the images I posted, it seems to be somewhat related to being unable to locate elements on iframe. Is it something to do with the #document part, which can be seen in the photo I posted. That somehow I need to .SwitchTo() another component of the webpage other than iframe?

Comment: @colossatr0n
Hey would you know by chance (seperate question) but how to become undetected by the site Indeed.com so that I can automatically submit my resume?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the `inputName`, you must switch the frame two times, please try this code to achieve what you mean :

```
driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("text-input-what")));
WebElement what = driver.findElement(By.id("text-input-what"));
what.sendKeys("Java Programmer");

WebElement where = driver.findElement(By.id("text-input-where"));
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    where.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
}
where.sendKeys("Jakarta");

WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='icl-Button icl-Button--primary icl-Button--md icl-WhatWhere-button']"));
submit.click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("title")));
WebElement thirdElement = driver.findElement(By.className("title"));
thirdElement.click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Apply Now')]")));
WebElement apply = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Apply Now')]"));
apply.click();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(1000);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("[src^='https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/x'")));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("[src^='https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/resume']")));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-applicant.name']")));
WebElement inputName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-applicant.name']"));
inputName.sendKeys("Adam Smith");

Thread.sleep(2000);
```